# Detecting if browser navigating to another page

Tags: javascript

I need to check if browser is navigating to another page or closing.
My idea is;

1. Create global variable `var isNavigating = false;`
2. Bind click event to make `isNavigating = true` of every anchor which will navigate to another page
3. Check if `isNavigating` true on body's `unload` event.

Any other ideas? Recommendations?

Comment: I think you might want to reword your question to make it clear you want to know whether they are navigating away or whether they are closing (i.e. to know which is happening, not just to know either is happening). As it's written just now, it's ambiguous as to whether you want to be able to tell the difference between them or not.

Comment: if a user typing a new website in the address bar and hitting enter is navigation, there's no way to tell the difference between that and the user closing the tab.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by the following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return;} 
</script>
```

However if you plan to cancel the navigaion, just don't bother. It's not possible as far as i know.

---

Code below checks if the user has clicked a link.

```
var checkAnchorClick = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").live("click", function () {
        checkAnchorClick = true;
    });
});

$(window).unload(function () {
    if (checkAnchorClick)
        alert("User clicked a link...");
    else
        alert("Something else...");
});
```

Comment: actually, you can "kind of" cancel it, but the user has to confirm: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/AA3qY/3/

Comment: @Ümit Akkaya http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/AA3qY/3/ shows that onbeforeunload works when clicking a link, closing the tab, closing the browser, or otherwise.